# Python store list as array in postgres database

Tags: python, postgresql

I'm trying to store data from my json file in postgres database. I've got problem storing arrays. When I've decoded my json file one of my fields look like this:

```
[{u'wartosc': u'0', u'tytul': u'Global'}, {u'wartosc': u'150', u'tytul': u'Poland'}]
```

When I'm trying to insert this in my database column (with text[] format) I'm getting error. The only accepted format is this:

```
{{Global,0},{Poland,150}}
```

And I've no idea how to do this.

I've tried with for loop, but It gives me values 0 then Global but I need first Global then 0. And it should work for all arrays like this, not only with keys 'wartosc' and 'tytul'

Schema of my table:
[image]

I'm trying to store my data in similar_web

Comment: Could you provide the schema of the table you want to insert into? And, post your attempts to solve it, if possible. Thanks.

Comment: Does the documentation for [Postgres arrays](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html) help? Also they're lists of single elements, not pairs, so your JSON pairs will not map cleanly. They have a particular format, and it's not JSON. I'll guess that your Python Postgres library will be able to help with the formatting. [Postgres also has JSON types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-json.html), different from arrays; you should probably be using that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass *a list of strings as a query parameter* so that the [PostgreSQL Python driver would automatically convert it to the `text[]` array type](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#adapt-list):

```
input_data = [{u'wartosc': u'0', u'tytul': u'Global'}, {u'wartosc': u'150', u'tytul': u'Poland'}]

data = [[item['tytul'], item['wartosc']] for item in input_data]

cursor.executemany("""
    INSERT INTO 
        TABLE_NAME
        (similar_web)
    VALUES
        (%s)
""", data)
```